# Undelete deleted answer: clanking vs. clinking

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-posts

I find it odd that [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/107063/23608) to the question [What's the action of banging two beers together called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107056/whats-the-action-of-banging-two-beers-together-called) was deleted for being a comment when it clearly provides an answer ("clank"). While it can certainly be improved, it is no less useful than the other answers ("clinked", "chinked", "cheers", and "toast") to the question.

The answerer is also new to SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I un-deleted the answer, since the user tried to edit it and make it more helpful once it had been deleted.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that her answer had been edited _after_ the delete.