# Can we revive a valuable answer that was removed?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-posts

In [a recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343863/why-do-we-crunch-numbers-when-solving-math-problems-particularly-in-accounti), there was an answer given that I thought was quite valuable, even though it didn't seem to be an answer that would be accepted as final / correct.  The answer had upvotes and discussion.

The user who gave it chose to delete it.  Is there a way to petition to have it back?

I don't have a cache of the page, otherwise I'd just re-add it myself. It wasn't picked-up by archive.org, or others, quickly enough.

---

I think it was a fairly high-rep user, so perhaps they'll notice this and chime-in.  Thanks all.

---

**ref:**

[The situation happened here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3821/23834), but the result was that mods undeleted it.  I'm hoping for some guidance about how anyone can solve this, without opening a meta question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The OP can undelete their own post (they may or may not want to, some people delete a post while making changes, eventually to leave it undeleted. Users with high enough rep can vote to undelete (I can see the answer as deleted).

Comment: The user has a tendency to delete answers when he considers them to be poor or unfairly criticized. It could be that his answer didn't convince him. It could be that he's digging through Google Books as we speak and tomorrow he'll undelete his answer. Can we say who the user is? The answer was perfectly informative nonetheless.

Comment: @Mitch that sounds like an answer.  Can this be petitioned by people without the rep to see?  Is it in a review queue at your rep?  Could low-rep users flag a question and write a custom comments to mods?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. The OP can undelete their own post (they may or may not want to, some people delete a post while making changes, eventually to leave it undeleted. Users with high enough rep can vote to undelete (I can see the answer as deleted).